# Why does costmap_2d::Costmap2D Class Reference use integers and not float?

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking through the documentation of costmap_2d::Costmap2D Class Reference I am seeing that a lot of the functionality for querying specific values about cells uses unsigned ints. For example;

`getCost (unsigned int mx, unsigned int my) const`
Get the cost of a cell in the costmap.

`getIndex (unsigned int mx, unsigned int my) const`
Given two map coordinates... compute the associated index.

`indexToCells (unsigned int index, unsigned int &mx, unsigned int &my) const`
Given an index... compute the associated map coordinates."

My question is why does it not use floats instead of unsigned ints? Because if I want to get the cost of a cell at map coordinate (25.25, 13.75), and the resolution is small, then the integer value (25, 14) will not be able to query the value of the true cell I want.

This may be a pretty bad question cause I am so new to this, but it has really been frustrating my understating and use of the ROS costmap2D.

Thanks ahead of time!

JJB

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319899/why-does-costmap_2d::costmap2d-class-reference-use-integers-and-not-float?/) by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 977 on 2019-03-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-29**:
I would say because a costmap is a discretised representation of a 2d area, and that discretisation was done at a certain resolution.

Given a certain resolution, it doesn't make sense to ask for a value at `.25` and `.75` of a cell, as there can be no more accurate data than the resolution allows.

If you're asking why you can't use "real coordinates" (ie: meters from the origin" or something similar") that would be something else.

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2019-03-29**:
I think that might be what I am really trying to understand, why can you not use meters from origin to work with the costmap.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-04-01**:
The [`Costmap2D::worldToMap` function](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/costmap_2d/html/classcostmap__2d_1_1Costmap2D.html#ab7134df329c4d4c174297f5db070c5a5) converts world coordinates (in meters, as doubles) to map coordinates that you can use with the other functions. Perhaps that's what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The costmap is internally stored as a one-dimensional array. Thus, for looking up data, you use the array index or the **cell** coordinates `mx` and `my`.

If you want to use metric coordinates, you need to first retrieve the respective **cell** coordinates using one of the [`worldToMap` functions](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/melodic-devel/costmap_2d/include/costmap_2d/costmap_2d.h#L135-L163) (inverse is `mapToWorld`). Those functions take care of converting metric to cell (or map) coordinates (and vice versa) observing the respective sizes in x and y as well as the resolution.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0